# seleccionar todos los hijos de elementos creados desde javascript

Tags: javascript

Les cuento que tengo un problema con la selección de hijos en java; Tengo un programa que crea objetos desde javascript, al cual, al hacerle click sobre dicho objeto, debe crearse un marco al rededor de él y luego, al hacer click fuera de este, debe eliminarse dicho marco (seleccionándolo y des-seleccionándolo), el problema es que al crear cada div, luego no se como hacer para referirme a todos los elementos creados por este método (todos los divs creados desde java). Aquí el código:

HTML

```
 <div class="principal">
        <div class="b" id="b">
         
          <span class="span1" id="span1" >
        </span>
            
          </div>
    </div>
```

javascript

```
    let agregar=""; //save elements from second text (will be disabled in the latest version)
    let almacenar=[]; //save all ele");ments from create
    let divb=[]; //save the elements from div of the principal list
    let span1=document.getElementById("span1");
    
let i=0;
    function buscar(){
    i=i+1;
    let div1=document.createElement("div");
    
div1.setAttribute("style","height:10em; width:97.8%; font-size:20px; padding-left:15px; padding-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; border-radius: 10px; background-color:#283747;color:#FFF; overflow:scroll;");
      
 div1.setAttribute("id",("b"+i));
      div1.addEventListener('click', f);
     span1.appendChild(div1);
}
     let sumar =[];
    let div1="";
    function f(e){
      // e.target es el elemento que lanzó el evento
      div1 =e.target;
     sumar.push(e.target.id);
     
     div1.setAttribute("style","height:10em; width:96.5%; font-size:20px; padding-left:15px; padding-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; border-radius: 10px; background-color:#283747;color:#FFF; border:5px solid #979A9A;");

   let impar1 =(sumar.length)/2;
     


if(Number.isInteger(impar1)==true){
           
       
        span1.parentNode.setAttribute("style","height:10em; width:97,8%; font-size:20px; padding-left:15px; padding-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; border-radius: 10px; background-color:#283747;color:#FFF;");
      }
      }
```

Intente con (span1.parentNode), pues todos los elementos div están dentro de (span1), pues fueron añadidos por (appendChild) al mismo, y pensé que seleccionaría todos los elementos hijos de este, pero no.
Más allá de eso, todo bien, incluso si cambio (span1.parentNode) por (div1) funciona perfecto, solo que des-selecciona solo el div pisado y necesito que lo haga con todos para que solo uno de los elementos tenga el margen de "seleccionado".

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

En tu código al estar usando `span1.parentNode` le estas aplicando en realidad esos estilos al div al nivel superior, que es el que tiene el id "b".

[parentNode](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp) sirve para seleccionar el elemento padre, si lo que quieres es seleccionar sus hijos debes usar [childNodes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp)

Esto devuelve una lista de todos los elementos hijos, es decir los elementos que estan dentro, luego deberías recorrer esa lista con un bucle, aplicando los estilos que necesites.

Comment: Buenas noches, intenté cambiar parentNode por ChildNode, Pero me dice que es indefinido. También intenté colocando el mismo Id a todos los divs que se crean pero sólo funciona cuando hay uno, ya cuando hay más me dice que no es función. Alguna idea?. Muchísimas gracias

Comment: Seguro que lo escribiste bien? se pone exactamente "childNodes", en el peor de los casos si apuntas a un div que no tiene hijos te retorna una lista vacia, nunca undefined.

Comment: buenas noches. si, ya intente con childNoes escrito de esa forma, de  todas formas gracias por la respuesta